# Is Java 8 supported on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, java

I just went to install Java 8 on my ancient laptop that runs Windows XP SP3.

Java pops up a message:

> Java 8 requires a newer version of Windows. You may continue with the installation, but for Java to work as specified we recommend upgrading your computer's operating system.

Will Java fail to work properly on Windows XP? Or is this just Oracle trying to be secure?

Comment: It's probably completely untested; no-one is ever going to bother testing anything against XP any more - you'll find out when you try to use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is Java 8 supported on Windows XP?

The technical answer is, **no**, it is no longer supported on Windows XP.

**This does not mean it will not work properly.**

Oracle just no longer supports the product in the same sense that Microsoft no longer supports Windows XP. Java 8 will still work properly on Windows XP but people/businesses with support contracts with Oracle will no longer be able to receive support for Java 8 if it is running on a Windows XP machine.

From [FAQ](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/winxp.xml) on java's website:

> **Why is Windows XP no longer supported?**
>
> As of April 8, 2014 Microsoft stopped supporting Windows XP and
>   therefore it is no longer an officially supported platform. Users may
>   still continue to use Java 8 updates on Windows XP at their own risk,
>   but we can no longer provide complete guarantees for Java on Windows
>   XP, since the OS is no longer being updated by Microsoft. We strongly
>   recommend that users upgrade to a newer version of Windows that is
>   still supported by Microsoft in order to maintain a stable and secure
>   environment.
>
> **Can I still install the latest Java on Windows XP? I see the message Java 8 requires a newer version of Windows** -- "You may continue with
>   the installation, but for Java to work as specified we recommend
>   upgrading your computer's operating system."
>
> Yes. As noted, users may still continue to use Java 8 on Windows XP at
>   their own risk, but we can no longer provide complete guarantees for
>   Java on Windows XP, since the OS is no longer being updated by
>   Microsoft.