# Can Java 8 work with windows xp?

Tags: windows-xp, java

Java 8 gives error message with Windows XP.  Can it still be used?  What are the latest issues?
Windows xp is no longer supported but will Java 8 still work on Windows XP computers since so many people still have windows xp?

Comment: Read [SuperUser question1169983](https://superuser.com/questions/1169983/is-java-8-supported-on-windows-xp)

Comment: This is still exactly the same question as the one linked as duplicate. The answer to that question is THE answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

#### Can Java 8 work with windows XP?

No, it is not supported. It requires Windows Vista or newer:

> [image]

Source [Oracle JDK 8 and JRE 8 Certified System Configurations](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html)

---

#### Windows XP and Java

**Why is Windows XP no longer supported?**

> As of April 8, 2014 Microsoft stopped supporting Windows XP and therefore it is no longer an officially supported platform. Users may still continue to use Java 8 updates on Windows XP at their own risk, but we can no longer provide complete guarantees for Java on Windows XP, since the OS is no longer being updated by Microsoft. We strongly recommend that users upgrade to a newer version of Windows that is still supported by Microsoft in order to maintain a stable and secure environment.
>
> Can I still install the latest Java on Windows XP? I see the message
>   Java 8 requires a newer version of Windows. You may continue with the installation, but for Java to work as specified we recommend upgrading your computer's operating system.
>
> Yes. As noted, users may still continue to use Java 8 on Windows XP at their own risk, but we can no longer provide complete guarantees for Java on Windows XP, since the OS is no longer being updated by Microsoft.
>
> I have a desktop/laptop with Windows XP. Will I continue to get automatic updates for Java when Oracle releases a security update?
>
> Yes, Security updates issued by Oracle will continue to be pushed out to Windows XP desktops.

Source [Windows XP and Java](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/winxp.xml)

Comment: It does _work_ though.